# implementing HDIV framework in grails application

Tags: grails, hdiv

I am looking at the HDIV framework to implement it in my Grails application. Looks like the framework is more user friendly to Struts/java based applications. They do say it can be configured on other frameworks. This is what it exactly says:

```
It is possible to use HDIV in applications that don’t use Struts 1.x, Struts 2.x, Spring MVC or JSTL, but in this case it is necessary to modify the application (JSP pages).
```

I see that we need to modify the editable and non editable data being sent to the server (one of the strategies is to cypher code the hidden field and add a state parameter to link urls.)
And in the response we get back this data and use a validate() function to do integrity checks.

The sample grails-HDIV project on GITHUB is really basic with no details.
Has anyone implemented it on grails?
Thanks
Priyank

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a plugin for this very thing.  I'll see if my company will let me release it and if so I'll inform you.

Comment: That will be really helpful, right now we are using the sanitizer plugin for all validation checks in our AbstractBaseController, extended by almost all controllers needing param sanitization.